# How explode string to array elements via regex?

Tags: php, regex, nested, expression

I want to convert nested brackets to array with keywords. Here is pattern:

```
preg_match_all('/(?=\{((?:[^{}]++|\{(?0)\})++)\})/', $string, $res);
```

And data which need to parse:

```
 employee { 
    cashier { salary = 100; } 
    technician { age = 44; } 
 }
```

Result, that I need:

```
Array
    (
        [employee] => Array (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [cashier] => Array
                        (
                            [salary] => 100
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [technician] => Array
                        (
                            [age] => 44
                        )

                )
        )
    )
```

But cant iterate within nested brackets. Stucked here. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: `preg_split` might be more suitable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a recursive approach here.

1. First, analyze the outer structure with `{` and `}` on both sides.
2. See, if we can find another nested structure
3. If not, look for `key = value` pairs and return them

A regex demo for the outer structure can be found on [**regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/oVLuka/1), [**a complete `PHP` demo**](http://ideone.com/ecG4hU) would look as follows:

```
<?php

$string = <<<DATA
 employee { 
    cashier { salary = 100; } 
    technician { age = 44; } 
 }
DATA;

// regular expressions    
$outer = '~(?P<key>\w+)\s*(?P<value>\{(?:[^{}]*|(?R))*\})~';

// inner, key = value
$inner = '~(?P<key>\w+)\s*=\s*(?P<value>\w+)~';

function parse($string) {
    global $outer, $inner;
    $result = array();
    // outer
    preg_match_all($outer, $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        $result[$match["key"]] = parse(
            substr($match["value"], 1, -1)
        );
    }

    // if not found, inner structure
    if (!$matches) {
        preg_match_all($inner, $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
        foreach ($matches as $match) {
            $result[$match["key"]] = $match["value"];
        }
        return $result;
    }
    return $result;
}

$result = parse($string);
print_r($result);
?>
```

---

This yields:

```
Array
(
    [employee] => Array
        (
            [cashier] => Array
                (
                    [salary] => 100
                )

            [technician] => Array
                (
                    [age] => 44
                )

        )

)
```